# How do I add a new entity that has a property which references an entity that is already created in a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `Project` table and a `Organization` table.

`Project` has a many to one relationship with `Organization`.

`Project` has a scalar property `OrganizationName` that references the primary key `Name` in `Organization`

I have a create view which is strongly typed to the `Project` model.

I collect input for the `Project.Organization.Name` property like so:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("Organization Name")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Organization.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Organization.Name)
    </div>
```

The controller handles the post like so :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Project project)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Projects.AddObject(project);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(project);
    }
```

How can I check to see if the new `project.Organization.Name` is already in the database? If it is, I want the new `project` to reference that tuple in the database and not attempt to add it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a `UNIQUE` constraint to the table. In a multi-user environment, that's the only way to be sure.
2. If you must know on the client, query the DB.

Like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Project project)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var org = db.Organizations.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Name.Equals(project.Organization.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        if (org != null)
        {
            project.Organization = org;
        }
        db.Projects.AddObject(project);

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(project);
}
```

Comment: This works great. I have one other question. How do I add a 'UNIQUE' constraint from within the ADO.Net Entity model builder?

Comment: Mostly, you don't. You need to do this on the DB server.